# Learning about Editing on ArcSDE?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase, editing

I am looking for some information about Editing in ArcSDE in a PDF or online that I would like to read about. I came to the USDA's Forest Service from the USDA NRCS and NRCS does not have ArcSDE. The US Forest Service is currently using their ArcSDE and I need to learn how it works.

We have Citrx for ArcGIS 10.2.2  and also have ArcGIS 10.2.2 on our PC as well.

Comment: Yes, SDE is a whole new ball park, not like editing a shapefile. Be *very* careful with geoprocessing that you don't send the results back to SDE (unless you really want to). A very wise decision to 'read the manual' before getting into it.

Comment: The Forest Service has a number of internal resources for education and policy as well.

Comment: @Vince  Yes I am well aware of that. They have course that I signed it up but won't be until August. That is the reason I am trying to get information to plan ahead..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend reviewing [About editing ArcSDE geodatabases](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//01m60000004r000000) which leads into:

- [A quick tour of the version editing process](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//003n000000w7000000) which:

> explains the process of editing a version; reconciling; resolving
>   conflicts; and, finally, posting the changes into the target version.

- [A quick tour of working with nonversioned data](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//003n000000z0000000) which explains:

> Editing nonversioned data that is stored in an ArcSDE geodatabase is
>   the equivalent of performing standard database transactions.

Answer (score 1):

This is the official [ESRI documentation on Editing](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/What_is_editing/01m500000003000000/).

These are the provided [Editing tutorials](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Introduction_to_the_Editing_tutorial/01m600000020000000/).

Comment: These pages all seem to be about generic editing tasks that are more targeted to single user workflows (shapefiles, file/personal geodatabases) when the asker says that he is looking for "information about Editing in ArcSDE".

Comment: This dichotomy exists because the *editing* isn't different, just the time when edits appear in the base table.